# Python function inside function but doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, workflow

I am trying to create a simple search engine to look inside a file. In order to reuse the code I separated the search function, but for some reason it just doesn't work the second time round.

The first time round it shows the result as it should but the second time I type a name it doesn't give me any result at all. Its like the `c` variable is not going in to the `searchpart(c, path)` function the second time round.

```
import os


def searchpart(c, path): 
    employees = os.walk(path)
    for root, dirs, files in employees:
        names = os.path.basename(root)
        if c.lower() in names.lower():
            print(root)
            os.chdir(root)
            for i in os.listdir():
                print("----->  {}".format(i))


def welcomepart(path):
    # this function allows to reuse the application after a name is search.
    c = input("\n-------> please introduce the name? \n")
    searchpart(c, path)


def mainfuntion():
    path = 'WORKERS'
    invalid_input = True
    print('______________ Welcome  ______________  \n ')

    while invalid_input:
        welcomepart(path)


mainfuntion()
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is wrong, but `os.chdir(root)` changes the current working directory.

Comment: problem is in your `searchpart` method.  If you replace the contents with `print(c, path)` you see that the `c` argument does change and get sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work-around seems to fix the problem:

```
def searchpart(c, path): 
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    employees = os.walk(path)
    for root, dirs, files in employees:
        names = os.path.basename(root)
        if c.lower() in names.lower():
            print(root)
            os.chdir(root)
            for i in os.listdir():
                print("----->  {}".format(i))
    os.chdir(cwd)
```

It just remembers which directory you were in before the function call and changes back before returning.

However, I'm sure there will be a solution where the line: `os.chdir(root)` is not needed.

Comment: The reason it was not working was.... When I change the current directory, I didn't change the directory back to the root folder.